# Text is not appearing at specified position in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, qgraphicsview

I have a `QGraphicsView` which contains many `QGraphicsItem` like rectangle, polylines etc.
I want to name each rectangle and name is on the rectangle.
Name should be centrally aligned i.e. half of the string name characters should be left side of mid position and half of the characters should be right side of mid position.
For that I used following psuedo code:

```
int firstPosition = GetMidPosition () - (strLength / 2);
int secondPosition = some points     
DrawText( firstPosition , secondPosition );
```

Now if I print co-ordinates of firstPosition, secondPosition , GetMidPosition() they comes perfectly as I expect.
But, the text does not come properly. I have to manually adjust it.

```
int firstPosition = GetMidPosition () - 6 *(strLength / 2);
```

Now it appears centrally. Why this is happening ? Co-ordinates are correct then why I have to manually adjust it.
I want to avoid that adjustment (i.e. 6 * )

> If tomorrow, I changed the font size of text, then I will have to
> change the multiplication factor 6 into something else. That should
> not be happened. How to write general purpose logic for this ?

[image]

Comment: With a proportional font, counting the characters is not a good way to find middle of text. (Please, consider that `W` has more width than `i` or `l`.) Instead, the alignment can be used. The text metrics and drawing functions can be used to determine the bounding box and its center or to draw the text respectively. FYI: [QFontMetrics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html), [QPainter::drawText()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawText)

Comment: Concerning _I want to avoid that adjustment (i.e. 6 * )_: The position is given in pixels but not as number of characters (like you might have expected). `6 *` is your approximation which might come quite close but won't work well for other text or a font with other metrics.